# Nested SELECT in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle

I'm trying to do as follows,

```
    SELECT ID_ESTACIONAMIENTO
    FROM ESTACIONAMIENTO
    WHERE '-33.52053824804071,-70.68874349999999' 
= (SELECT LATITUD_ESTACIONAMIENTO||','||LONGITUD_ESTACIONAMIENTO FROM ESTACIONAMIENTO);
```

But returns

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

How can I get ID_ESTACIONAMIENTO WHERE *values* (*in this case '-33.52053824804071,-70.68874349999999'*) are being compared with a concat query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better approach is to just check the latitude and longitude columns separately:

```
SELECT ID_ESTACIONAMIENTO
FROM ESTACIONAMIENTO
WHERE LATITUD_ESTACIONAMIENTO = '-33.52053824804071' AND
      LONGITUD_ESTACIONAMIENTO = '-70.68874349999999'
```

Note that you may not need to use quotes if your latitude/longitude data be stored in a numeric column.

If you want to "fix" your exact current query, then just use the concatenated columns from the outer query directly in your `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT ID_ESTACIONAMIENTO
FROM ESTACIONAMIENTO
WHERE LATITUD_ESTACIONAMIENTO||','||LONGITUD_ESTACIONAMIENTO =
      '-33.52053824804071,-70.68874349999999'
```

By the way, the reason behind your error, which is self-explanatory, is that the subquery returns more than one row.  Actually, it should return *every* row from the `ESTACIONAMIENTO` table.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a subquery, and you don't need to concatenate either.

```
SELECT ID_ESTACIONAMIENTO
FROM   ESTACIONAMIENTO
WHERE  LATITUD_ESTACIONAMIENTO  = -33.52053824804071
  AND  LONGITUD_ESTACIONAMIENTO = -70.68874349999999;
```

If the input is a string that concatenates latitude and longitude, you should break it up instead of concatenating the values from the table. Something like - if the input is `str = '-33.52053824804071,-70.68874349999999'` -

```
... WHERE LATITUD_ESTACIONAMIENTO  = to_number(substr(str, 1, instr(str, ',') - 1))
      AND LONGITUD_ESTACIONAMIENTO = to_number(substr(str, instr(str, ',') + 1));
```